# jquery 'find' cant find gx:Track

Tags: jquery, kml

My problem is Jquery find function.

this is my kml code ~

```
.
..
...
<Placemark>
    <name>Happy Dinner 2011-05-21 16:57</name>
    <styleUrl>#msn_track-0</styleUrl>
    <gx:Track>
        <when>2011-05-21T07:57:44Z</when>
        <when>2011-05-21T07:58:29Z</when>
        <when>2011-05-21T07:59:12Z</when>
        <when>2011-05-21T07:59:41Z</when>
        <when>2011-05-21T07:59:53Z</when>
        <when>2011-05-21T08:00:29Z</when>
        ...
        <gx:coord>127.03971 37.51795 99.59999999999999</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>127.03998 37.51816 101.8</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>127.03958 37.51816 106.8</gx:coord>
        ..
        .
```

as you know I can access dom using find,

```
//data is the xml(kml) file loaded.
$(data).find('Placemark')
```

this works correctly, return object array.

but,

```
$(data).find('gx:Track')
```

this doesn't work, return empty jquery object.

```
$(data).find('gx:coord')
```

also doesn't work.

anyone who know the reason and solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that it see's the `:track` part of the string as a jQuery pseudo-selector (like `:first-child` etc).

You can escape the `:` by putting a `\\` before it, so your selector would become:

```
$(data).find('gx\\:Track')
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for the explanation of controlled selector characters.

Answer (score 1):

escape the `:` with `\\`

Like this:

```
$(data).find('gx\\:Track')
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that jQuery selectors do not recognize XML namespaces.

You can try this: `$(data).find('gx\:coord')` but something tells me it will not work either.